# marklogic PII access

Tags: marklogic, readonly, marklogic-dhf, pii

I created a user that have a role with **rest-read** only. And an Entity that have an ID as **primary key** and **PII**. (The ID is a property of the instance). 
So when the user search some documents using a rest API, the ID is not hidden!

I followed this tutorial but no success https://docs.marklogic.com/datahub/security/pii/enable-pii-using-quickstart.html

FYI : User role

```
{
  "role-name": "researcher",
  "description": "application user",
  "role": ["rest-reader"],
  "privilege": []
}
```

Do you know what I am missing ?
Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the data is not well mapped to the entity. So the pii config was not applied to it.